# access a function inside a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, google-maps

I'm having trouble accessing a function inside an object.

My setup is as such..

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){$(document).ready(CareersInit);});

function CareersInit()
{
     CAREERS = new Careers();
     CAREERS.init();
}

function Careers()
{
     this.init = function()
     {
         function initialize() 
         {
             //Usual google maps stuff here
         }
     }

    $('body').bind('onload', function() {
        initialize();
    });
}
```

With this setup, initialize doesn't run but if I take my google maps variables/functions out of the initialize function then it work's but my understanding (from google docs) is that initialize should always be a function that contains the google maps variables/functions etc.

Even if that is the right way to go it would be great to find out how to access functions when they are inside an objects method just for debug purposes in the console. I thought

```
CAREERS.init.initialize();
```

would work but it doesn't.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Giles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `initialize` function is truly private to the function you're putting on `this.init`. It cannot be accessed from outside that `this.init` function unless you do something to make it accessible.

But I don't think you need that extra layer of indirection:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){$(document).ready(CareersInit);});

function CareersInit()
{
     CAREERS = new Careers();
     CAREERS.init();
}

function Careers()
{
    var self = this;

    this.init = function()
    {
        //Usual google maps stuff here
    };

    $('body').bind('onload', function() {
        self.init();
    });
}
```

Separately, though, your code is trying to initialize the `Careers` instance twice. You have Google's load callback calling jQuery's `ready` function which then calls your `CareersInit` function which calls `CAREERS.init`. But you *also* have the `Careers` constructure scheduling a separate page load callback. (That one may or may not run, it depends on when Google fires the `setOnLoadCallback` callback.)

I'd get rid of one of those calls to `init`.

In a comment on another answer, you've said you want to know what the "best" way to do it is. I'd have to know more about what you're doing, but I'd probably do it like this:

```
(function() {
    // Our single Careers instance
    var CAREERS;

    // Ask Google to call us when ready
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
        // Just in case Google is ready before the DOM is,
        // call our init via `ready` (this may just call
        // us immediately).
        $(document).ready(CareersInit);
    });

    // Initialize our single instance    
    function CareersInit()
    {
         CAREERS = new Careers();
         CAREERS.init();
    }

    // Constructor    
    function Careers()
    {
    }

    // Career's init function
    Careers.prototype.init = Careers_init;
    function Careers_init()
    {
        //Usual google maps stuff here
    }

})();
```

...except that if you're going to just have *one* instance (and you're sure that's not going to change), there's really no call for a constructor function at all:

```
(function() {
    // Our data; the function *is* the single object
    var someData;

    // Ask Google to call us when ready
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
        // Just in case Google is ready before the DOM is,
        // call our init via `ready` (this may just call
        // us immediately).
        $(document).ready(CareersInit);
    });

    // Initialize our single instance    
    function CareersInit()
    {
         someData = "some value";
    }
})();
```

There, the function scope *is* the single instance; no need for separate constructor functions, [playing games with `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html), etc. Note that we're not creating any globals, `someData` is scoped to the anonymous function. The call that the interpreter makes to that function *is* our single object.

If you're ever going to need more than one `Career` instance, then great, definitely go the constructor function route. But if not, there's a lot less fuss involved if you use the object you already have (the execution context of the call to the function).

---

**Off-topic**: **Strongly** recommend declaring your `CAREERS` variable. With your code as it is now, you're falling prey to [The Horror Of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help and good tip on the self.init(); Quick question though, why does this have to be assigned to a variable?

Comment: @Giles: Because `this` in JavaScript is not like `this` in some other languages you might have used, like Java, C++, C#, ... In JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by *how the function is called*, not *where the function is defined*. When jQuery calls your `onload` handler, it will set `this` to be the `window` object, not your `Career` instance. So we take advantage of the fact that you're already defining that handler as a closure over the constructor function call's context and use a variable to remember a reference to the object being constructed. (See the link I added about `this`.)

Comment: Ah ok yeah that makes sense, I forgot about jQuery's this. Thanks for the rest of the info, it will take a while to dissect and understand but thats very helpful.

Comment: @Giles: No worries, glad that helped. Note that `this` isn't jQuery's, it's JavaScript's. jQuery uses it in much the way any JavaScript code does, since JavaScript gives us such control over it. :-)

Comment: I have just read up a little bit more on constructors so its starting to make more sense. Im definitely only going to have one instance of careers so im going with the second example you provided. I'm not too sure what you mean by 'Our data; the function *is* the single object' and why you would set the 'someData' variable, is that so it's accesible to other functions etc? In my current CareersInit's this.init function I have all the usual variables and functions to setup a google map such as mapoptions and geocoding functions so do I put all of those inside the 'someData' variable?thanks

Comment: @Giles: Re `someData`, I'm assuming you're going to need to have some enduring state. If not, just don't have any vars in the scoping function. When I say the call to the function *is* the object, I mean it literally: Every call to a function creates an *execution context* which (waves hands) holds the vars and such within the function. That context endures as long as anything has a reference to anything in it (like callbacks), even after the function has returned. More: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html

Comment: Ah ok, cheers. Think it's going to take a bit more reading on OO javascript but im starting to get it. Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

`initialize` is a private function inside `init`, which means it is inaccessible outside `init`.

What exactly is the purpose of defining things twice?

```
 this.init = function()
 {
         //Usual google maps stuff here
 }
```

Comment: No purpose, I just want to know the best way of doing it, thanks for the help.